# Me sale un número de rows incorrecto

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en Mysql llamado `visits` en una BD llamado `counter`el cual sirve para paginas en serie y determinar el enlace que tendrán los elementos `<a>anterior<a>` y `<a>siguiente<a>` :

| Orden | Pagina | Vistas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | www.sitio.com/capitulo1 | 0 |
| 2 | www.sitio.com/capitulo2 | 0 |

En workbech, uso el comando `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM counter . visits` y me sale 2 filas, como tiene que ser, SIN EMBARGO, cuando lo llevo a php mediante:

```
$page = $access -> query("SELECT pagina FROM counter . visits ORDER BY orden") -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo count($page);
```

Me sale 1 fila. ¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump` a `$page` ¿qué obtienes?

Comment: Tu consulta esta tal cual la tienes aquí, ya que tienes un punto entre counter y visits, posiblemente te este retornando el numero de filas afectadas que en este caso es una la del mensaje

Comment: @BetaM me sale `array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "www.sitio.com/capitulo1" }`

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia lo escribo con esa sintaxis porque así es como workbech me demanda hacerlo, sino no funciona, pero en el php le quite el nombre de la BD y el punto, e igual da el mismo resultado de antes.

Comment: @ArturoViñasSalazar y ¿por qué en una consulta haces un COUNT y en la otra no?

Comment: @BetaM porque en realidad no es que necesite el número de filas, sino la tabla en forma de array con índices numéricos, pero no funciona bien porque el array extraido termina incompleto con menos items del que debería; al ver que algo no andaba bien usé `count($page)` para descartar, nada más.

Comment: Seguramente el método `fetch_array()` lee solo una fila, de acuerdo al apuntador. En todo caso, deberías ver si tu clase de base de datos cuenta con un método `fetch_all()` para devolver todas las filas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el resultado de la consulta `$page` omitiendo el `fetch_array`, es un objeto `MySQLi`. Luego `fetch_array()` no trae todos los resultados en un solo array, si no que va moviendo el apuntador a una fila por vez en el objeto y trae esa fila en formato array. Como le estas aplicando el método justo en la ejecución del query, solo va a traer la primera fila.

Una forma de comprobarlo:

```
$query = "SELECT pagina FROM counter.visits ORDER BY orden";
$page = $access->query($query);
var_dump($page->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)); // Apuntador en pos 0
// www.sitio.com/capitulo1
var_dump($page->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)); // El apuntador se mueve
// www.sitio.com/capitulo2
```

Para traer todos los resultados:

```
while($row = $page->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    // Hacer lo que quieras con $row
}
```

O también puedes usar [fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)